# how to keep application running in background? keep collecting data?

Tags: android, database, gps

UPDATED AT BOTTOM

I have written an application that logs the users position, current speed, average speed and top speed. I would like to know how to make the application do the following things:

1. prevent the screen from turning off while it is open on the screen
2. if the user opens another app or returns to the home screen, gets a call etc, the app should keep collecting data
   (or would it be better to just write all data to a database everytime the location is updated? and maybe have a button to signify when to start and stop collecting data?)

here is the code that I have written. (feel free to use it if you want and if you have any recommendations on how I might improve it I am very open to constructive criticism :D )

```
package Hartford.gps;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GPSMain extends Activity implements LocationListener {

LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

//text views to display latitude and longitude
TextView latituteField;
TextView longitudeField;
TextView currentSpeedField;
TextView kmphSpeedField;
TextView avgSpeedField;
TextView avgKmphField;

//objects to store positional information
protected double lat;
protected double lon;

//objects to store values for current and average speed
protected double currentSpeed;
protected double kmphSpeed;
protected double avgSpeed;
protected double avgKmph;
protected double totalSpeed;
protected double totalKmph;

//counter that is incremented every time a new position is received, used to calculate average speed
int counter = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    run();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, this);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    super.onPause();
}

private void run(){

    final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    //Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {

            counter++;

            //current speed fo the gps device
            currentSpeed = round(newLocation.getSpeed(),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            kmphSpeed = round((currentSpeed*3.6),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            //all speeds added together
            totalSpeed = totalSpeed + currentSpeed;
            totalKmph = totalKmph + kmphSpeed;

            //calculates average speed
            avgSpeed = round(totalSpeed/counter,3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            avgKmph = round(totalKmph/counter,3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            //gets position
            lat = round(((double) (newLocation.getLatitude())),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            lon = round(((double) (newLocation.getLongitude())),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
            longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);             
            currentSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);
            kmphSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kmph);
            avgSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.avgspeed);
            avgKmphField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.avgkmph);

            latituteField.setText("Current Latitude:        "+String.valueOf(lat));
            longitudeField.setText("Current Longitude:      "+String.valueOf(lon));
            currentSpeedField.setText("Current Speed (m/s):     "+String.valueOf(currentSpeed));
            kmphSpeedField.setText("Cuttent Speed (kmph):       "+String.valueOf(kmphSpeed));
            avgSpeedField.setText("Average Speed (m/s):     "+String.valueOf(avgSpeed));
            avgKmphField.setText("Average Speed (kmph):     "+String.valueOf(avgKmph));

        }

        //not entirely sure what these do yet
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, locationListener);
}

//Method to round the doubles to a max of 3 decimal places
public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode)
{
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
    BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
    return rounded.doubleValue();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

BOTH PROBLEMS SOLVED THANKS TO ANSWERS FROM [Marco Grassi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764165/marco-grassi) AND [Marcovena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491125/marcovena).

New Code:

```
package Hartford.gps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GPSMain extends Activity   {

//text views to display latitude and longitude
static TextView latituteField;
static TextView longitudeField;
static TextView currentSpeedField;
static TextView kmphSpeedField;
static TextView avgSpeedField;
static TextView avgKmphField;
static TextView topSpeedField;
static TextView topKmphField;

//objects to store positional information
protected static double lat;
protected static double lon;

//objects to store values for current and average speed
protected static double currentSpeed;
protected static double kmphSpeed;
protected static double avgSpeed;
protected static double avgKmph;
protected static double totalSpeed;
protected static double totalKmph;
protected static double topSpeed=0;
protected static double topKmph=0;

//counter that is incremented every time a new position is received, used to calculate average speed
static int counter = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wL = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK,"My Tag");

    wL.acquire();

    startService(new Intent(this, Calculations.class));

    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);             
    currentSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed);
    kmphSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kmph);
    avgSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.avgspeed);
    avgKmphField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.avgkmph);
    topSpeedField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topspeed);
    topKmphField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topkmph);

}

static void run(){

    latituteField.setText("Current Latitude:        "+String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText("Current Longitude:      "+String.valueOf(lon));
    currentSpeedField.setText("Current Speed (m/s):     "+String.valueOf(currentSpeed));
    kmphSpeedField.setText("Cuttent Speed (kmph):       "+String.valueOf(kmphSpeed));
    avgSpeedField.setText("Average Speed (m/s):     "+String.valueOf(avgSpeed));
    avgKmphField.setText("Average Speed (kmph):     "+String.valueOf(avgKmph));
    topSpeedField.setText("Top Speed (m/s):     "+String.valueOf(topSpeed));
    topKmphField.setText("Top Speed (kmph):     "+String.valueOf(topKmph));

}

}
```

and

```
package Hartford.gps;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Calculations extends Service implements LocationListener  {

static LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

private static final String TAG = "Calculations";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    run();

}

private void run(){

    final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    //Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {

            GPSMain.counter++;

            //current speed for the GPS device
            GPSMain.currentSpeed = round(newLocation.getSpeed(),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            GPSMain.kmphSpeed = round((GPSMain.currentSpeed*3.6),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            if (GPSMain.currentSpeed>GPSMain.topSpeed) {
                GPSMain.topSpeed=GPSMain.currentSpeed;
            }
            if (GPSMain.kmphSpeed>GPSMain.topKmph) {
                GPSMain.topKmph=GPSMain.kmphSpeed;
            }

            //all speeds added together
            GPSMain.totalSpeed = GPSMain.totalSpeed + GPSMain.currentSpeed;
            GPSMain.totalKmph = GPSMain.totalKmph + GPSMain.kmphSpeed;

            //calculates average speed
            GPSMain.avgSpeed = round(GPSMain.totalSpeed/GPSMain.counter,3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            GPSMain.avgKmph = round(GPSMain.totalKmph/GPSMain.counter,3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            //gets position
            GPSMain.lat = round(((double) (newLocation.getLatitude())),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            GPSMain.lon = round(((double) (newLocation.getLongitude())),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            GPSMain.run();
        }

        //not entirely sure what these do yet
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, locationListener);

}



//Method to round the doubles to a max of 3 decimal places
public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode)
{
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
    BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
    return rounded.doubleValue();
}


public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

UPDATE FOR  shababhsiddique

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Calculations extends Service{
static LocationManager locationManager;
static LocationListener locationListener;
private static long timerTime = 1;
private static float timerFloatValue = 1.0f;
private Context context;
private int counter = 0;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {return null;}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    context = this;
    update();
}

protected void update(){        
    final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

    //Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
            counter++;
            if(GPSMain.GPSHasStarted==0){
                GPSMain.previousLocation = newLocation;
                //gets position
                GPSMain.lat = round(((double) (GPSMain.previousLocation.getLatitude())),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                GPSMain.lon = round(((double) (GPSMain.previousLocation.getLongitude())),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                GPSMain.startingLocation = GPSMain.previousLocation;
                GPSMain.routeLat.add(Double.toString(GPSMain.startingLocation.getLatitude()));
                GPSMain.routeLon.add(Double.toString(GPSMain.startingLocation.getLongitude()));
                GPSMain.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                GPSMain.GPSHasStarted++;
                Toast.makeText(context, "GPS Connection Established", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startService(new Intent(context, AccelerometerReader.class));
                Toast.makeText(context, "Accelerometer Calculating", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Have A Safe Trip!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //gets position
            GPSMain.lat = round(((double) (newLocation.getLatitude())),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            GPSMain.lon = round(((double) (newLocation.getLongitude())),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            if (newLocation.distanceTo(GPSMain.previousLocation)>2.0f){
                GPSMain.distanceBetweenPoints = GPSMain.distanceBetweenPoints + newLocation.distanceTo(GPSMain.previousLocation);
            }

            //current speed for the GPS device
            GPSMain.mpsSpeed = newLocation.getSpeed();
            if (GPSMain.mpsSpeed>GPSMain.topMps) {GPSMain.topMps=GPSMain.mpsSpeed;}

            //store location in order to calculate distance during next iteration.
            GPSMain.previousLocation = newLocation;

            if (counter % 20 == 0){
                GPSMain.routeLat.add(Double.toString(GPSMain.previousLocation.getLatitude()));
                GPSMain.routeLon.add(Double.toString(GPSMain.previousLocation.getLongitude()));
            }
        }

        //not entirely sure what these do yet
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 20, locationListener);
}

//Method to round the doubles to a max of 3 decimal places
public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode){
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
    BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
    return rounded.doubleValue();
}

//formats the time taken in milliseconds into hours minutes and seconds
public static String getTimeTaken(long end, long start){
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    String formattedTime = "", hourHour = "", hourMin = ":", minSec = ":";
    long timeTaken = end-start, hour = 0, min = 0, sec = 0;
    timerTime = timeTaken;
    timeTaken = (end-start)/1000;
    if (timeTaken>9 ){
        hourHour = "0";
        hourMin = ":0";
        if (timeTaken>=60){
            if (timeTaken>= 3200){
                hour = timeTaken/3200;
                timeTaken = timeTaken%3200;
                if (hour>9){
                    hourHour = "";
                }
            }
            min = timeTaken/60;
            timeTaken = timeTaken%60;
            if (min >9){
                hourMin = ":";
            }
        }
        sec = timeTaken;
        if(sec%60<10){
            minSec = ":0";
        }
        return formattedTime = (hourHour+hour+hourMin+min+minSec+sec);
    }
    sec = timeTaken;
    minSec = ":0";
    hourMin = ":0";
    hourHour = "0";
    return formattedTime = (hourHour+hour+hourMin+min+minSec+sec);
}

public static double averageSpeed(){

    //calculates average speed
    if (timerTime==0){timerTime=1;}
    timerFloatValue = (float) timerTime;
    timerFloatValue =  timerFloatValue/1000;
    return GPSMain.avgMps = GPSMain.distanceBetweenPoints/timerFloatValue;
}

//rounds the float values from the accelerometer
static String roundTwoDecimalFloat(float a){
    float b = a/9.8f;
    String formattedNum;
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    formattedNum = nf.format(b);
    return formattedNum;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution, but why are you implementing LocationListener to the service? you are not using the overrides, you are using the anonymous inner LocationListener instead.

Comment: Hi, I just noticed your comment now. It has been quite a while since I was working on this project and I cannot remember a lot of the details. In all honesty I am possibly using bad coding practice as I am only a novice programmer.

What exactly was the flaw that you found? I would be interested to see my error and improve my coding.

Comment: not an error actually, i am a novice android coder too, but i just noticed that you have implemented LocationListener to your class and and never defined what to do at the class level, you used another anonymous location listener in the program instead -

public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {

            GPSMain.counter++;
......} is there something i am missing?

Comment: I reopened the project and had a look at that class again. This is an old version of the class. I have edited the original post and pasted the class as I have it now. You should know that this is an old project that I am no longer working on.

Comment: Hi, may i ask how you cache the background collected data? Write to database or just a binary file? thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Question 1: You must acquire a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) . There are multiple types of wakelock, depending if you want only the cpu on or also the screen.

Question 2: You should do your collecting data stuff inside a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) and separate the graphical interface from the collecting data. The Service will continue to collect the data until you stop it if you implement it correctly.

Comment: Agree with @Marco Grassi. 
You can also take a look at  [My Tracks](http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/) application from Google. It does what you want to implement in our app --

Comment: Thanks for the replys and suggestions :) I would vote it up but apparently I dont have enought points yet or something.

I'll try these out and post the results back here

Comment: WakeLock keeps the device awake, not your particular app alive. Android can kill your background app if it needs memory. Generally you need to use Service.