# Run accelerometer in the background unsuccesfull

Tags: android, eclipse, service, android-sensors

trying to make a simple step counter. Everything works fine until the screen goes off. Thats why I tried to move the sensor event to a service as described in

[how to keep application running in background? keep collecting data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291729/how-to-keep-application-running-in-background-keep-collecting-data)

I did as best as I can but cant find the error.
here is activity code

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btnStart, btnStop;
    static TextView tvX, tvY, tvZ;
    static boolean started = false;
    protected static double x,y,z;

    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wL = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK,"My Tag");

        wL.acquire();

        startService(new Intent(this, Calculations.class));

        tvX= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.steps);
        tvY= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dist);
        tvZ= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cals);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvX.setText("0.0");
        tvY.setText("0.0");
        tvZ.setText("0.0");
    }

    static void run() {
        if (started) {
            tvX.setText(Double.toString(1.1));
            tvY.setText(Double.toString(y));
            tvZ.setText(Double.toString(z));
        }
        else {
            tvX.setText(Double.toString(5.5));
            tvY.setText(Double.toString(y));
            tvZ.setText(Double.toString(z));            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnStart:
            btnStart.setEnabled(false);
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
            started  = true;
            // run();
            break;
        case R.id.btnStop:
            btnStart.setEnabled(true);
            btnStop.setEnabled(false);
            started = false;
            //run();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the service code

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
public class Calculations extends Service implements SensorEventListener  {

    private float[] gravity = new float[3];
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private static final String TAG = "Calculations";
    static boolean started = false;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            final float alpha = 0.8f;

            gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
            gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
            gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

            Main.x  = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
            Main.y  = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
            Main.z  = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
            Main.run();
        //}
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check have You Mentioned this Service in Process in your Manifest file..

```
android:Process=".AnyName"
```

Please Check this. If it is not there,please add this. It should be work